# Extract from QueryDict/json in Django 1.5

Tags: django, json, request

From `self.request.body` I have

```
changes%5B0%5D%5B%5D=1&changes%5B0%5D%5B%5D=query&changes%5B0%5D%5B%5D=first&changes%5B0%5D%5B%5D=second
```

I know %5B = "[" og %5D = "]", so the string is

```
changes[0][]=1 & changes[0][]=query & changes[0][]=first & changes[0][]=second
```

With `self.request.POST` I get

```
<QueryDict: {u'changes[0][]': [u'1', u'query', u'first', u'second']}>
```

How can I use these values? I need to store the values '1', 'query', 'first', and 'second'.

I've tried `json.loads(self.request.body)` which results in error `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`.

Comment: Is this being sent by jQuery, by any chance? If so you should use `jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;` to disable the mis-feature that converts to this format.

Comment: It is. It makes it much more clean, but `json.loads(self.request.body)` gives same error

Comment: Well, now I don't think it's JSON at all - it's probably just form-encoded data, which you can get via `request.POST.getlist('changes')`.

Comment: You're right. It works with `self.request.POST.getlist('changes')[0].split(',')`. Thank you :-)

Comment: @DanielRoseman, you should answer this. Your comment seems to work from what I can see.