# Django validation of json POST fails unless jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;

Tags: jquery, python, django, json, validation

So I have an AJAX post JSON to Django, which is picked up in request.body in my view. Request.body looks like so:

```
{"c": {"cellid": 5}, "b": {"cellid": 8}, "e": {"cellid": 3}, "i": {"cellid": 9}, "k": {"cellid": 11}, "j": {"cellid": 10}, "l": {"cellid": 12}, "n": {"cellid": 7}, "q": {"cellid": 1}, "r": {"cellid": 4}, "w": {"cellid": 2}, "v": {"cellid": 6}}
```

I want to take this into a JSON object for validation and cleaning processes, but, when I try:

```
json.loads(request.body)
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

and SimpleJSON says:

```
simplejson.loads(request.body)
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Any pointers as to what's going wrong? When I JSON lint the above it is valid, so what is the issue with the decoding?

Interestingly, from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15886125/781909), it looks like this was the fault of jQuery, as

```
jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
```

fixed the issue in javascript. I'm not sure why this is the case, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

views.py

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.utils import simplejson
if form.is_valid():
template = "my_template.html"
html = render_to_string(template,{"c": {"cellid": 5}, "b": {"cellid": 8}, "e": {"cellid": 3}, "i": {"cellid": 9}, "k": {"cellid": 11}, "j": {"cellid": 10}, "l": {"cellid": 12}, "n": {"cellid": 7}, "q": {"cellid": 1}, "r": {"cellid": 4}, "w": {"cellid": 2}, "v": {"cellid": 6}})
response = simplejson.dumps({'success':'True','html':html})

try it, it should work.
```